# How to get acknowledgements from ListenTCP, ListenWebSocket in NiFi

Tags: apache-nifi

I have created below flow in apache-nifi.

[image: NiFi flow]

I sent a HL7 message to to listentcp on a specific port and it went through all the steps, but It didn't send any acknowledgement back. 
What needs to be done for getting acknowledgements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TCP is a network level protocol which is acknowledging packets at the network level. Needing to send an acknowledgement response on the connection is an application specific protocol which ListenTCP would have no idea about, how would it know what needs to be sent back? and the expected response could be different for every application.

You would need to build a processor similar to ListenTCP, but that was specific to your application protocol that would respond with what your application is expecting. An example of this is NiFi's ListenRELP processor which implements the RELP protocol and sends acknowledgments for each RELP frame it processes.

Comment: The problem is not with the format of reply. I am not getting any kind of reply... I wrote a python program to send an HL7 message and the program is waiting for reply. And with an HL7 simulator tool I tried, I selected _Treat any incoming data as an ACK_, but it also didn't receive any reply.

Comment: The concept of a reply is specific to your application that you wrote, it is not part of any general TCP connection.